# C++ Builder Firemonkey Live Bindings not displaying data?

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, livebindings

Working on an application using C++ Builder and the Firemonkey platform.
I have a form which I have used the Live Binding Wizard to bind a grid to a datasource (datasource is on another form). Underlying database is a TurboDB Table.
In using the Live Binding wizard, I create a new StringGrid and link it to the newly created binding source.

In the IDE Designer, the data comes up as shown in the picture below:
[image: in IDE data comes up]

Now after I compile and run, no data comes up.

[image: Data not showing at runtime]

I am kind of new to firemonkey and miss the ease of the VCL where you can link up Tables with Datasources then to the data controls.   Live binding wizard is new to me so any help would be appreciated.